# Android games popular resolutions

Tags: android, graphics

I'm trying to settle on a resolution to start looking for better textures for my first android game. I saw a popular Android game company's (Magma Mobile) Facebook page and it had its game's screenshots in many different aspect ratios and resolutions in their Facebook page. Some images were 750x500 others were 720x423.

My question is, what are the actual game's original resolutions and what are the most popular resolutions right now for Android mobiles? I'm considering 800x480 (which is 1,66 aspect ratio), because it is between 1,5 and 1,777. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) page contains information on device statistics updated approximately every month. The "Screen Sizes and Densities" section shows information on physical screen size and display density distribution.

If you combine the screen size and density information above using the following image (from the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page):

[image: diagram showing screen size and density buckets]

you should be able to calculate the most common screen pixel dimensions in use today.

Answer (score 1):

My phone's resolution is 1080p, my 2 flatmates' a lot of my friends'as well. 480 is very outdated. If you're making a game my guess is you'll use an engine. My take on it is you should aim for fullHD or 4k and let the engine handle the lower resolutions. If it ends up being very demanding on the hardware I guess you should try lower ones. I'm not experienced with game engines so I'm trying to tackle this from the consumer side. Hope this is useful.